# How can I run this code without syntax error?

Tags: module, verilog, xor, bitwise-xor

This code gives me a syntax error when I run it on cmd.  Any help?

```
module xor (a, b, c); 
 input a, b; 
 output c; 
 wire c, not_a, not_b; 
   not a_invert (not_a, a); 
   not b_invert (not_b, b); 
   and A1 (x, not_a, b); 
   and A2 (y, not_b, a); 
   or Result (c, x, y); 
endmodule 

module xor_test(a, b); //test bench
   input a, b;
   wire c;
   xor x(a,b,c);
   initial
   begin
      $monitor("c=%b",c);
   end
endmodule

module main();
   wire a=0, b=1 ; 
   xor_test t1(a,b);
endmodule
```

Comment: حبيبة أحمد Did you read the link about what to do when you've gotten an answer that helped to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You get a syntax error because you are trying to use `xor` as a module name.  Since `xor` is a reserved keyword in Verilog, it is illegal to use it as a module name.  You can rename it to something like `xor1`:

```
module xor1 (a, b, c); ////////// CHANGED
 input a, b; 
 output c; 
 wire c, not_a, not_b; 
   not a_invert (not_a, a); 
   not b_invert (not_b, b); 
   and A1 (x, not_a, b); 
   and A2 (y, not_b, a); 
   or Result (c, x, y); 
endmodule 

module xor_test(a, b); //test bench
   input a, b;
   wire c;
   xor1 x(a,b,c);  ////////// CHANGED
   initial
   begin
      $monitor("c=%b",c);
   end
endmodule

module main();
   wire a=0, b=1 ; 
   xor_test t1(a,b);
endmodule
```

I changed the 2 lines with comment `CHANGED`.

`xor` is a gate type, just like `or`, `and` and `not` in your code.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 28. *Gate-level and switch-level modeling*.

Here is a running example on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/CJNe)